# Google Maps API, Adding a User-Customised Map To A Website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I currently have a map displayed on my page with various markers and settings. See below;

```
var options = { 



        zoom: 7,

        center: latlng,

        scrollwheel: true,

        navigationControl: true,

        mapTypeControl: false,

        scaleControl: false,

        draggable: true,

        streetViewControl: false,

        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,

        panControl: false,

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN

      };
```

I was wondering if there is any variable/option that allows my to make the map read from a custom map that a user makes on Google Maps?

**So a user will go onto the Google Maps website and add their own markers and locations - this is the map I want to read into my website.**

The main aim here is to have a list of markers(which I have) but what I am lacking is a way to show more 'smaller' locations in an area when an initial marker is clicked...

**So if you click on a marker which is placed on London, that will zoom in to show more markers scattered in the London area.**

Thanks!

Comment: need to explain in a lot more detail what you mean by `read map user creates` and what you mean by `smaller locations`

Comment: is idea to have user paste link to their map and you parse it? If so, create a demo link in google maps that has some markers on it and post link here

Comment: When you say " a custom map that a user makes on Google Maps" are you talking about [Google "My Places"](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1705614)?  Data from those maps can be exported as KML.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes - sorry I wasn't sure what it was called.. can you explain it further?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming questions.  A tutorial on My Maps doesn't belong here in the comments and is off topic for StackOverflow in general.  If your question is "how do I put content from Google My Maps on a Google Maps API map", that would be on topic (if you tried to do that and ran into trouble), but you should search as it may have already been answered.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site I've used many times - I know what it's for. Even the inclusion of javascript should surely show that I'm doing more here than 'My Maps', the question WAS to have a map created in 'My Maps' as an API Map on a personal webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zoom map when marker is clicked, You have to add event listener when you initialize map and marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {    
   map.setZoom(parseInt(yourZoom));    
   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  
});
```

So when you click a marker, zoom property will be set, in this case, at value of yourZoom.

For more details, you can [check documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)